# Object Creation in visual studio 2010 c++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, oop, c++-cli

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong here?

I have two classes and I have to access the value of class A variables into Class B and then compare them and this is what I am doing and I am unable to access the variable

```
public ref class A : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

    public:
    String^ name;
    String^ address;

    private: System:: void foo()
    { 
        name=textBox1->Text;
        address=textBox2->Text;
    }
}`

public ref class B : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

    public:
    String^ name1;
    String^ address1;
    A^ obj;

    private: void foo()
    {
     MessageBox::show(obj->name);
     MessageBox::show(obj->address); 
    }
}`
```

This gives me an error saying syntax error on line `A^ obj;` when I have one and saying missing type specifier both these classes are in a different header files

Comment: This is not C++, looks like it could be C#.  The C++ language doesn't have the syntax: `public ref class`.  Also, the `public` in front of a method should have a colon, ':', after it.  The `^` after `String` indicates you are using CLI.  I recommend changing language tags.

Comment: It's definitely not C#, or at least not any sort of C# I've seen.....

Answer (score 0):

In an attempt to be helpful, and i will probably get some down votes... haters be nice.

This is C++/CLI, so asking about just C++ will get you no help as that is a very special type of C++ that i will not attempt to explain. Gordon Hogenson has written an excellent book on the subject.

Class A has a Class B
However, you show nothing that would set name and address as part of foo() being executed

If you are suggesting this is a compile error, this compiles for me

```
      public ref class A : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
      {

             public:
              String^ name;
              String^ address;

             private:  void foo()
             {
                name = "Test this";
                address ="Test 2";
             }
        };

        public ref class B : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
        {

                 public:
                   String^ name1;
                   String^ address1;
                   A^ obj;

                  private: void foo()
                  {
                      MessageBox::Show(obj->name);
                      MessageBox::Show(obj->address);
                  }
          };
```

I do not think it will do what you expect, but that is a different issue if you are battling a compile time error. To address the compile time issue, provide the real .h and .cpp and not a hybrid that you think is  the problem.

Regarding the setting of A within B, this is a variable scope issue of OO and is independent discussion of compile time

Comment: appreciate it. I have been getting some downvotes and they wont even explain why they did that. I have just started working on visual studio so all this is quite frankly new to me. I thought I could ask questions here and learn from experience of others but I guess thats not the case.. I will update my question shortly.